# How can I reduce margins of text button in TkInter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Time at the bottom is a button (text='00:00:00') and time at the top is label (text='00:00:00'). They have both the same fonts set. Is there any way to reduce the margins of the red button? I want them to be the same size but then the red one looks like that.

[image]

```py
    def __init__(self, sets_num):

        self.screen = Frame(root)
        self.background = BG_START_WORK
        
        bg_canvas = Canvas(self.screen, width=460, height=990)
        bg_canvas.create_image(230, 498.3, image=self.background)
        bg_canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=12, columnspan=3)

        timer = Label(self.screen, text='00:00:00', font=FONT2, bg='#393E46', fg='#FFFFFF')
        timer.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=S, pady=(98, 0))

        timer_to_set = Button(self.screen, text='00:00:00', background='#D65A31', activebackground="#D65A31",
                              bd=0, fg='#F7D6D7', activeforeground='#F7D6D7', font=FONT2)
        timer_to_set.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=S, pady=(100, 0))
```

I've tried playing with 'height' and 'width' parameters but it doesn't help.

Comment: Setting the `width` option to same value on both the label and button works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The padding (margin) between the butter outline and the letters can be changed only by changing the font size and changing the width and height of the button. Like:

```
timer_to_set = Button(self.screen, font='12', width=20, height=10, text='00:00:00',background='#D65A31', activebackground="#D65A31",
                          bd=0, fg='#F7D6D7', activeforeground='#F7D6D7',)

timer_to_set.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=S, pady=(100, 0))
```

With trial and error method, change the value of font, width and height and check for the optimum result.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `width` option to same value, for example 8, on both the label and the button works for me.

Below is a simple example based on your provided code without using class:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
screen = Frame(root)

FONT2 = ("Arial", 24)

timer = Label(screen, text='00:00:00', font=FONT2, bg='#393E46', fg='#FFFFFF', width=8)
timer.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=S, pady=(98, 0))

timer_to_set = Button(screen, text='00:00:00', background='#D65A31', activebackground="#D65A31",
                      bd=0, fg='#F7D6D7', activeforeground='#F7D6D7', font=FONT2, width=8)
timer_to_set.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=S, pady=(10, 0))

screen.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]